# Removing Duplicates From String

Tags: php, regex, curl, memory, proxy

Basically I have a script, It checks a page for proxies and adds it to a string then checks it for duplicates and outputs them.

The only issue is the page being checked easily has 20k+ proxies on it so doing this makes it take about 3-4 minutes straight and most times will give me a bytes exhausted error or else max_execution error.

Is there any way to check for duplicates and just output them any quicker or easier?

```
<?php

ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

set_time_limit(1000);

//Curl Setup;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'x');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

//Execute Curl;
$page = curl_exec($ch);

//Regex For Matching Proxies;
preg_match_all('/(\d){1,3}\.(\d){1,3}\.(\d){1,3}\.(\d){1,3}:(\d){1,5}/ism',$page,$output);

//Foreach Proxy Found, Output it;
foreach($output[0] as $op){ $proxies .= $op."\n"; }

//This doesnt work
implode('\n',array_unique(explode('\n', $proxies)));

//Output each proxy
echo $proxies;

?>
```

Oh, Also, When it does get the proxies with no errors and puts them into a textarea using AJAX it makes serious lag issues. You wont be able to click on anything thats how much lag there is. Not sure if this whole issue is more to do with AJAX but not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store them in an array and than use array_unique.

```
$proxies = array ();
for($i =0, $max = count ($output[0]];$i <$max; $i++) {
  $proxies[] = $output [0][$i];
  // unset to reduce memory usage. Unsure if it'll actually help but
  unset($output [0][$i]);
}
echo implode("\n", array_unique  ($proxies));
```

Or use the values as keys to an associative array. Not sure if this would be any faster though

```
$proxies = array ();
foreach($output[0] as $op){
  $proxies[$op] = null;
}
echo implode("\n", array_keys  ($proxies));
```

Comment: Youre answer solved my Memory issues, The first bit worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to this (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php#70786 i don't have test it) a possible way for what you want would be something like the following code:

```
//Populate the array maybe different for your needs
$proxies = array();
foreach($output[0] as $op) {
    $proxies[] = $op;
}
$unique_proxies = array_keys(array_flip($proxies));
```

***Request:

It would be nice if you could make a benchmark using your data and tell us the results.

Comment: Just a pointer making an empty array linked to a variable to use the [] (Add Index) isn't required.

Comment: You're answer is good, It is much faster at using Curl. It took about 0.2 seconds to load :) The only issue is that since its an array, I would need to do a foreach $array as $value and output the value making it do the exact same thing, making a lot of memory issues and time issues (VarDup and Print_R dont have this issue) Any ideas?

Comment: Just tried this foreach to output the proxies and as expected I get a fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes). The only way I know of to fix this is: ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');. But as people are saying this isn't a good practice. Any idea?

Comment: Can you show me your latest snippet of code and a few elements of your proxies array so i will be able to test it?

Comment: Its fine, The other answer actually solved the memory issue. I highly appreciate your help anyway!

Comment: Nice! I will mark the question as favorite because it was a good one.